# How is automatic dependency generation with GCC and GNU Make useful?

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++, gnu

I found many ways online to use the `-M`-type flags for GCC (or G++) to automatically generate dependencies in your Makefile. All approaches seem similar, I implemented [this one](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

All arguments I could find in favor are along the lines of: **It helps you in that you don't have to manage dependencies manually.**
I don't see why.

Consider the following files:

**main.c**

```
#include "foo.h"
int main() { foo(); return 0; }
```

**foo.h**

```
void foo();
```

**foo.c**

```
#include "foo.h"
void foo() { ... }
```

I would say that main.c *depends* on foo. However, when I run `make main.o`, foo is not built. The dependency file main.d contains (which explains why foo has not been built):

```
main.o: main.c foo.h

foo.h:
```

Now if I were to create an executable (e.g. `app: ; $(CC) -o app main.c`, with or without auto-dependency generation flags), I would still have to **manually** specify that it depends on foo.o.

So my question is: how does the auto-dependency generation save me any work if I still have to specify the dependency on foo.o?

Comment: What do you mean by `"main.c depends on foo"`?  What's `foo` here?  Likewise for `"...manually specify that it depends on foo.o"`: what's `it`?  Note that the compiler can only generate dependencies that are visible within the translation unit.  It doesn't know anything about link time dependencies such as the fact that `main` might use function definitions from -- and, therefor, depend on -- `foo.o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `main.c` does not depend on `foo`. To be more exact `main.c` does not depend on anything but the text editor. It's the `main.o` that depends on `main.c` and `foo.h` as those files are required to compile `main.o`. Your final binary should depend on `main.o` and `foo.o` to be linked together, but it needs to be explicitly stated - neither `make` nor linker will find out what files you want to build together.

What this autodependency gives you is the notation that when `foo.h` changes, `main.o` will need to be recompiled (as this is included from `main.c`) even though `main.c` itself did not have any changes.

Answer (score 0):

*"I would say that main.c depends on foo."*

Not quite; `main.o` depends on `foo.h`, and `app` depends on `foo.o`.

Automatic dependency generation can take care of that first dependency; the compiler finds `#include "foo.h"` in `main.c` and takes note of it.

The second dependency you must take care of. Neither the compiler nor Make can deduce it. (Bear in mind that not every header file has a corresponding source file with a matching name.)